# The problem of the formula of Fourier series

Tags: analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

My textbook states this question as follows :

Let $f$ be a $2\pi$-periodic Riemann integrable function defined on ${\bf R}$ .Then show that  $f$ can be written as $$f(\theta)\sim\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n\geq1}\bigg\{\bigg(\widehat{f}(n)+\widehat{f}(-n)\bigg)\cos(n\theta)+i\bigg(\widehat{f}(n)-\widehat{f}(-n)\sin(n\theta)\bigg)\bigg\}~,$$
provide that we given $f(\theta)\sim\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}$ and $\widehat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ .

$\rule{18cm}{2pt}$

However, I think the conclusion may be not true , in general , when we don't make an assumption $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}}|\widehat{f}(n)|<+\infty$ 
since this question may involve the issue of absolute convergence of a function. Or is there another way to show this conclusion which does not use the property of absolute convergence  ?

The following is my attempt  via the additional hypothesis $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}}|\widehat{f}(n)|<+\infty$ :

\begin{align}
&\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}\\
=&\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}-\{0\}}\widehat{f} {(n)}\bigg(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)\bigg)\\
=&\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}_{<0}}\widehat{f} {(n)}\bigg(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)\bigg)+\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}_{>0}}\widehat{f} {(n)}\bigg(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)\bigg)\\
=&\color{red}{\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}_{>0}}\widehat{f} {(-n)}\bigg(\cos((-n)\theta)+i\sin((-n)\theta)\bigg)+\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}_{>0}}\widehat{f} {(n)}\bigg(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)\bigg)}\\
=&\color{blue}{\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}_{>0}}\bigg\{\widehat{f}(-n)\bigg(\cos((-n)\theta)+i\sin((-n)\theta)\bigg)+\widehat{f}(n)\bigg(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))\bigg)\bigg\}}\\
=&\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}_{>0}}\bigg\{\widehat{f}(-n)\bigg(\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)\bigg)+\widehat{f}(n)\bigg(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))\bigg)\bigg\}\\
=&\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n\geq1}\bigg\{\bigg(\widehat{f}(n)+\widehat{f}(-n)\bigg)\cos(n\theta)+i\bigg(\widehat{f}(n)-\widehat{f}(-n)\sin(n\theta)\bigg)\bigg\}
\end{align}

I think the equality is true form red to blue if we impose this following condition : 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}|=\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}}|\widehat{f}(n)||\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)|=\sum_{n\in{\bf Z}}|\widehat{f}(n)|<+\infty$$

Any advice or comment will be appreciated . Thanks for considering my request .

Comment: The problem doesn't ask you to show that $f=$ that sum, just that $f\sim$ that sum. So convergence has nothing to do with it; you just have to show that the coefficients are the Fourier (sine and cosine) coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we define 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\widehat{f}(n)e^{in\theta},
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\widehat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}\\
&=\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\widehat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\widehat{f}(-n)e^{-in\theta}\\
&=\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\widehat{f}(n)+\widehat{f}(-n)\right)\cos(n\theta)+i\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\widehat{f}(n)-\widehat{f}(n)\right)\sin(n\theta).
\end{align*}
So 
\begin{align*}
\widehat{f}(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\widehat{f}(n)+\widehat{f}(-n)\right)\cos(n\theta)+i\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\widehat{f}(n)-\widehat{f}(n)\right)\sin(n\theta)\rightarrow\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f}(n)e^{in\theta},
\end{align*}
and the result follows.